# how to add a header to multiple cols

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

The sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<- structure(list(Name = c("B2", "A2", "B3", "A3", "B4", "A4"), 
    Var1.x = c(29, 56, 25, 11, 0, 58), Var2.x = c(65, 35, 
    15, 11, 0, 58), Var3.x = c(95, 632, 25, 11, 0, 58), Var1.y = c(29, 
    56, 25, 11, 0, 58), Var2.y = c(29, 56, 25, 11, 0, 58), Var3.y = c(29, 
    56, 25, 11, 0, 58)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I will need to write it as an excel file. How can I add a header to the output? Is it a way I can modify df to achieve this goal? if we need to your merge cell to build header, is it a way to find the cols that have `.x` and merge to `Subject x` instead of counting the col number?

The ideal output is sth that looks like this:
[image]

Currently I have my codes:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Question")
writeData(wb, sheet = "Question", x = df, colNames = TRUE, startCol = 1, startRow = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb, paste("C:/Question.xlsx"),overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Column 5 is named `Var1.x` in your picture. `names(df)[5]` is `"Var1.x...5"`. The header above column 5 is `Subject Y` in your picture. Could you clarify what output you really want?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have update the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with the `xlsx` package:

```
library(xlsx)
library(stringr) # For str_extract. regmatches is very cumbersome 
workbook <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(workbook, sheetName = "Question")
row <- createRow(sheet, 1)
cells <- createCell(row, seq_along(colnames(df)))

suffixes <- unique(na.omit(str_extract(colnames(df),"(?<=\\.)\\w$")))
for(suf in suffixes){
  ind <- grep(paste0("\\.",suf,"$"),colnames(df))
  setCellValue(cells[[ind[1]]], paste0("Subject ",toupper(suf)))
  setCellStyle(cells[[ind[1]]], CellStyle(workbook) + Alignment(horizontal = "ALIGN_CENTER"))
  addMergedRegion(sheet, startRow = 1, endRow = 1,
                  startColumn = ind[1],
                  endColumn = tail(ind,1))
}

addDataFrame(as.data.frame(df), sheet, row.names=FALSE, startRow=2)
saveWorkbook(workbook,'df.xlsx')
```

[image]